# Was The Blob in the Steve McQueen version or the 1980s remake sentient?

Tags: aliens, plot-device

Maybe not explicitly so, but hinted at that the creature has, for example, some understanding of humans being separate creatures? I thought that in the remake it animates the dead body of a kid, almost as if it is teasing the human who sees this.

Comment: Regarding the dead body that was reanimated, which specific scene are you referring to? The one with the teenage boy and girl in the car?

Comment: @LogicDictates: no, it has been 35 years but i think the kid was like 9 and in bed.

Comment: Doesn't ring a bell. I wonder if you might be thinking of a scene from a different movie here. I think the only preteen we see killed in the 1988 remake is killed while being chased through the sewers. He's the friend of Shawnee Smith's character's kid brother.

Comment: The reanimated dead kid sounds like the finale of the movie version of Dean Koontz's horror novel "Phantoms". The story's monster is The Ancient Enemy, an intelligent, prehistoric shape-shifting amorphous monster - reminiscent of Lovecraft's Shoggoths. In the film, the monster takes the form of a child that the sheriff hero had accidentally killed in the past.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, it is sentient (but may not be intelligent)

[Merriam-Webster defines sentience as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sentient)

> 1 : responsive to or conscious of sense impressions 
> sentient beings

This appears to be the intended definition.

The Blob seeks living things. It acts to eat living creatures, follow them, and in fact solves problems to get around or over obstructions to get at human things.

It receives stimuli where living things are and responds to their direction to eat them.

However, whether it is *intelligent* is another matter entirely.

Comment: The phrasing in releseabe's question suggests they were using the word 'sentient' in [the way that it's used in _Star Trek_](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sentience), i.e. to refer to intelligence. Ergo, this doesn't really answer the intended question.

Comment: Predatory on the order of a shark or Komodo dragon, but not a Xenomorph. But I agree with you about intelligence because that's not definable.